# Custom Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm building custom content filtering system using custom radio buttons. 
There are some problems that occurred on the way like not being able to keep a radio selected on mouse out' or 'on class change', jQuery's selector wouldn't track the new class so an events are not fired, and so on..

This is what I've succeeded so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/Birowsky/gVwQf/2/

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/gVwQf/3/

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the tricks, that has not been successfully completed by anyone without relying onto horrible looking scripting orimages. There are always some catch in every workaround. However, you can check following links.

- http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
- http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/06/11/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
- http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/